Is .ToListAsync() available in .net8 maui android app?
I am working on a .net maui android app .
I have big data like 8000 records.
I save data once in a SQLite db when the customer installs the app, then I retrieve from the database for filtering my data.
I want to await the query but I only see .ToList() as the app throws null exception and crashes.
Is ToListAsync() available in .net8  maui android app or how can I await my results through linq?
This my code for the datacontext class
public class DataContext
{
    private const string DbName = "IdealDiagnosisDb3";
    public static string DbPath = Path.Combine(FileSystem.Current.AppDataDirectory,DbName);
    private SQLiteConnection Database;

    private async Task init()
    {
        //File.Delete(DbPath);

        if (File.Exists(DbPath))
        {
            return;
        }

        Database = new SQLiteConnection(DbPath, SQLiteOpenFlags.Create | SQLiteOpenFlags.ReadWrite | SQLiteOpenFlags.SharedCache);
            
        Database.CreateTable<Drug>();
        List<Drug> drugs = new List<Drug>(){big data };

        foreach (Drug drug in drugs)
        {
            Database.Insert(drug);
        }

        Database.CreateTable<TradeDrug>();
        List<TradeDrug> TradeDrugs = new List<TradeDrug>(){ big data };
        foreach (TradeDrug TradeDrug in TradeDrugs)
        {
            Database.Insert(TradeDrug);
        }
    }
        
    public async Task<List<Drug>> LoadAllDrugsAsync()
    {
        init();
        return Database.Table<Drug>().ToList();
    }

    public async Task<List<TradeDrug>> LoadAllTradeDrugsAsync()
    {
        init();
        return Database.Table<TradeDrug>().ToList();
    }
}

This my code for HomeViewModel class
public partial class HomeVM(DataContext dataContext) : BaseVM
{
    private readonly DataContext _dataContext = dataContext;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private List<Drug> _drugs;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private List<TradeDrug> _tradeDrugs;

    private List<Drug> DrugsWithoutFilter;

    private List<TradeDrug> TradeDrugsWithoutFilter;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private string _searchName;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private string _placeHolderText;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private string _drugName;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private string _diagnosisId;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private string _diagnosisName;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private bool _isDrugSelected;

    [ObservableProperty]
    [NotifyCanExecuteChangedFor(nameof(SearchCommand))]
    private bool _isTradeRadioButtonChecked;

    partial void OnIsTradeRadioButtonCheckedChanged(bool value)
    {
        Search();
    }

    [ObservableProperty]
    private Drug _selectedDrug;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private int _countDrugs;

    public async Task InitializeDrugsAsync() 
    {
        DrugsWithoutFilter = await _dataContext.LoadAllDrugsAsync();

        Drugs = DrugsWithoutFilter;
        CountDrugs = Drugs.Count();
        TradeDrugsWithoutFilter = await _dataContext.LoadAllTradeDrugsAsync();

        TradeDrugs = TradeDrugsWithoutFilter;

        IsDrugSelected = false;
        IsTradeRadioButtonChecked = false;
    }

    [RelayCommand]
    private async Task Search()
    {
        if (!IsTradeRadioButtonChecked)
        {
            PlaceHolderText = "Enter Active Ingredient";

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchName))
            {
                IsBusy = true;
                Drugs = DrugsWithoutFilter.Where(x => x.DrugName.ToLower().Contains(SearchName.ToLower())).ToList();

                CountDrugs = Drugs.Count();
                IsBusy = false;
            }
            else
            {
                Drugs = DrugsWithoutFilter;

                CountDrugs = Drugs.Count();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            PlaceHolderText = "Enter Trade Name";

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchName))
            {
                IsBusy = true;
                TradeDrugs = TradeDrugsWithoutFilter.Where(x => x.TradeDrugName.ToLower().Contains(SearchName.ToLower())).ToList();

                CountDrugs = TradeDrugs.Count();
                IsBusy = false;
            }
            else
            {
                TradeDrugs = TradeDrugsWithoutFilter;

                CountDrugs = TradeDrugs.Count();
            }
        }
    }
}

error
no .tolistasync() in intellesense suggestion

.tolistasync() , is it available in .net8 maui android app
Yes this is available in .NET 8

how to find it , only .tolist() availble in maui app .

i added the error and the intellisense suggestion

To use async methods, you must first use SQLiteAsyncConnection

Do you really need an async method to do this?

ToListAsync() is part of EntityFramework package/dll. But I don´t see any EntityFramework references in your code. So I think you cannot use it with SQLLiteConnection.
Think about switching to SQLiteAsyncConnection.
But without big changes you could just switch your code to:
 private void Init() 
 { 
      // your code here
 }

or (with little overhead, because async/await are actually not necessary)
 private async Task Init() 
 { 
     // your code here

     // at the end
     await Task.CompletedTask;
 }

or (again little overhead)
 private Task Init() 
 { 
     // your code here

     return Task.FromResult(yourResult);
 }

So in your code:
public class DataContext
{
    private const string DbName = "IdealDiagnosisDb3";
    public static string DbPath = Path.Combine(FileSystem.Current.AppDataDirectory,DbName);
    private SQLiteConnection Database;

    private void init()
    {
        //File.Delete(DbPath);

        if (File.Exists(DbPath))
        {
            return;
        }

        Database = new SQLiteConnection(DbPath, SQLiteOpenFlags.Create | SQLiteOpenFlags.ReadWrite | SQLiteOpenFlags.SharedCache);
            
        Database.CreateTable<Drug>();
        List<Drug> drugs = new List<Drug>(){big data };

        foreach (Drug drug in drugs)
        {
            Database.Insert(drug);
        }

        Database.CreateTable<TradeDrug>();
        List<TradeDrug> TradeDrugs = new List<TradeDrug>(){ big data };
        foreach (TradeDrug TradeDrug in TradeDrugs)
        {
            Database.Insert(TradeDrug);
        }
    }
        
    public Task<List<Drug>> LoadAllDrugsAsync()
    {
        init();
        return Task.FromResult(Database.Table<Drug>().ToList());
    }

    public Task<List<TradeDrug>> LoadAllTradeDrugsAsync()
    {
        init();
        return Task.FromResult(Database.Table<TradeDrug>().ToList());
    }
}


my issue with LoadAllDrugsAsync() and LoadAllTradeDrugsAsync() as i make query from sqlite database . i installed the package and still not able to find .tolistasyc() extention . i tried other solutions in your answer but still have same problem

I have added one solution to my answer for your code. Make Init not async and return Task.FromResult() as a quick fix,

gives me error CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Collections.Generic.List<Icd.Models.Drug>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Icd.Models.Drug>'

You still have to await the calls like: TradeDrugsWithoutFilter = await _dataContext.LoadAllTradeDrugsAsync();
